# Drop Shadow not working in separate class, only general

Tags: css, filter, dropshadow, css-filters

I am creating a page with multiple slanted divs on it. This divs should have a "border" (which I am currently generating with a drop-shadow).

Using the filters on an extra .dropshadow class does not work, but it does show up when I am using the filters on the <main> tag instead.

Q1: why is this happening?

Q2: is there another solution for generating the borders aside dropshadows? With DS I am running into problems with opacity on the colored element. It's still solid although defined as rgba with .75 opacity and only gets semi transparent when I am removing the dropshadow from the element.

**[Codepen](https://codepen.io/SchweizerSchoggi/pen/qBmyXLj)**

```css
body {
  padding: 0 0 200px 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: transparent url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1622495546323-5dac33dedb01?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2167&q=80")  no-repeat top center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: Arial;
  line-height: 1.6rem;
}

html {
  --pad: calc(20px + 5vw);
}

main {
  font-family: Arial;  
  
  /* Here it DOES work (remove filters in .dropshadow class to test it): */
  /*
  --b:20px;
  
  filter:
   drop-shadow(var(--b) 0px 0px #f2f2f2) 
   drop-shadow(0px var(--b) 0px #f2f2f2) 
   drop-shadow(calc(-1*var(--b)) 0px 0px #f2f2f2) 
   drop-shadow(0px calc(-1*var(--b)) 0px #f2f2f2);
  */
}

.dropshadow {
  /* Here it does NOT work: */
  --b:20px;
  
  filter:
   drop-shadow(var(--b) 0px 0px #f2f2f2) 
   drop-shadow(0px var(--b) 0px #f2f2f2) 
   drop-shadow(calc(-1*var(--b)) 0px 0px #f2f2f2) 
   drop-shadow(0px calc(-1*var(--b)) 0px #f2f2f2);
}

.content__slant {  
  /*background: orange;*/
  background-color: rgba(250, 174, 64, .75);
  position: relative;
  padding: 120px 40px 120px 40px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 20%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 80%);
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<main class="content">
    
  <div class="content__slant dropshadow">
    <p>
      We try your eye, but can you change everything? submit your meaningless business jargon to be used on the site!, but that will be a conversation piece this red is too red can you pimp this powerpoint, need more geometry patterns I have an awesome idea for a startup, i need you to build it for me. The flier should feel like a warm handshake. The animation does not work, when i print the page you might wanna give it another shot, or can you turn it around in photoshop so we can see more of the front can you make the blue bluer? jazz it up a little, can you please send me the design specs again?
    </p>
    <p>
        I know somebody who can do this for a reasonable cost. Anyway, you are the designer, you know what to do can you make the logo bigger yes bigger bigger still the logo is too big can you use a high definition screenshot, in an ideal world. Remember, everything is the same or better in an ideal world can you please send me the design specs again?
    </p>
    <h3>Thats not what i saw in my head at all!!</h3>
    <strong>... and so it ends.</strong>
  </div>
  
</main>
```

Comment: Drop-shadow will show around transparent edges inside the clip-path.  Outside clip-path anything is cut off. Here only the parent can apply the filter around the children if it has no background.

Comment: Is there another option for creating the borders aside from drop-shadow?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I am asking because I need to have the colored area semi transparent but not the borders themself, which not seems to be possible with the drop-shadow